# Postgres: Is there a way to tie a User to a Schema?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema

In our database we have users:  A, B, C.

Each user has its own corresponding schema:  A, B, C.

Normally if I wanted to select from a table in one of the schemas I would have to do:

```
select * from A.table;
```

My question is:

Is there a way to make:

`select * from table`

go to the correct schema based on the user that is logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior for PostgreSQL.  Make sure your `search_path` is set correctly.

```
SHOW search_path;
```

By default it should be:

```
search_path
--------------
"$user",public
```

See PostgreSQL's [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html) on schemas for more information.  Specifically this part:

> You can create a schema for each user with the same name as that user. Recall that the default search path starts with $user, which resolves to the user name. Therefore, if each user has a separate schema, they access their own schemas by default.
>
> If you use this setup then you might also want to revoke access to the public schema (or drop it altogether), so users are truly constrained to their own schemas.

**Update RE you comment:**
Here is what happens on my machine.  Which is what I believe you are wanting.

```
skrall=# \d
No relations found.
skrall=# show search_path;
  search_path   
----------------
 "$user",public
(1 row)

skrall=# create schema skrall;
CREATE SCHEMA
skrall=# create table test(id serial);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "test_id_seq" for serial column "test.id"
CREATE TABLE
skrall=# \d
            List of relations
 Schema |    Name     |   Type   | Owner  
--------+-------------+----------+--------
 skrall | test        | table    | skrall
 skrall | test_id_seq | sequence | skrall
(2 rows)

skrall=# select * from test;
 id 
----
(0 rows)

skrall=#
```

Comment: sweet, thanks for the info... It doesn't seem to be working correctly for me then.

Comment: Added some information, it works as expected for me.  Not sure what the issue could be.  What version of PostgreSQL?